# Proving statement about regularity of operators

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations

Let $V$ is finite dimensional vector space over some field $F$. Let $A,B$ are linear operators, i.e. $A, B \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that if $A$ is regular and $B$ is not regular then $AB$ nor $BA$ is regular.

My attempt:
On finite dimensions, to disprove that operator is regular it is enough to show, that operator is not monomorphism or epimorphism.

- $AB$ is not regular

If $B$ is not regular, then $B$ is neither monomorphism or epimorphism. It means that there exists $x \in V, x \neq 0$ such that $Bx = 0$. Then, from regularity of $A$ follows that $A(Bx) = 0$, which means that non-zero $x \in \operatorname{Ker}(AB)$ and $AB$ is not regular.

- $BA$ is not regular

In this case, I would like to disprove epimorphism of $BA$. It means, that there exists $z \in V$ such that for all $x \in V$ $Bx \neq z$.

I'm having trouble proving last point. How can I find $z$ such that it would obey such property? Is my overall strategy correct?

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is not an epimorphism, then there is some $z\in V$ such that $z\notin B(V)$.  But $B(A(V))\subseteq B(V)$, so $z\notin B(A(V))=BA(V)$ and thus $BA$ is not an epimorphism.